# Background image in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, background

I am creating an application with a fixed background (2208x2208) for every screen, that is why I am setting the background in the application delegate. The current code inside the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method is:

```
func setBackground() {
    let width = self.window!.frame.size.width// * UIScreen.mainScreen().nativeScale
    let height = self.window!.frame.size.height// * UIScreen.mainScreen().nativeScale

    let size = max(width, height)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: width, height: height))

    UIImage(named: "background.jpg")?.drawInRect(CGRectMake(-(size - width) / 2, -(size - height) / 2, size, size))

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image!)
}
```

This works like it supposes, but with one issue. The image looks like it is scaled down and scaled back to the scale of the screen. So on an iPhone 6 Plus it doesn't look sharp. This might be expected behaviour since the window size is not the full resolution. But when I multiply it with the native scale, only 1/9th the image (upper left) is shown. Is there a way (besides providing separate resolutions for this image) to show it without scaling first?

A second issue, for if anyone know the solution for this. The image is shown behind a UINavigationController where every view inside the UIViewController has a transparent background. This works and shows the background, but one problem, the background turns a little darker when navigation to another view. Probably because the animation. Is there a way to hide this animation? Inside the UIViewControllers (there are only two yet, but this will be inside a class which will be overridden) is the following code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.view.alpha = 1.0
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: {
        self.view.alpha = 0.0
    })
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}
```

Even without this code, it still turns darker before it goes light again. It looks like the view still as a dark opaque background with a very low alpha and when presenting the second screen, it lays both backgrounds on top of each other until the second screen is completely presented and the first one will be removed.

Thanks!